# Get all elements with Jsoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I'm trying to find all elements inside this kind of html:

```
<body>
My text without tag
<br>Some title</br>
<img class="image" src="url">
My second text without tag
<p>Some Text</p>
<p class="MsoNormal">Some text</p>
<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
</ul>
</body>
```

I need get all elements include parts without any tag. How a can get it?

**P.S.**: I need to get array of "Element" for each element.

Comment: *Parts w/o tag* are still in some tag, aren't they?

Comment: How do you imagine this "*array of "Element"*" should look like? What should be its content?

Comment: @Pshemo i think this can be "Elements" class with all this elements

Comment: And what each of this elements inside `Elements` class should contain precisely?

Comment: Lets focus on `<body>` tag. What should element representing `body` contain? Should it contain text from body? Or maybe should it contain entire body structure? In that case what should be second element?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure if you are asking to retrieve all the text within the html. to do that, you can simply do the following:

```
String html; // your html code
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html); //parse the string
System.out.println(doc.text());   // get all the text from tags.
```

**OUTPUT:**

> My text without tag Some title My second text without tag Some Text
>   Some text 1 2

Answer (score 0):

Just in case if you using a html file, you can use the below code and retrieve each tag that you need. The API is Jsoup. You can find more examples in the below link http://jsoup.org/

```
File input = new File(htmlFilePath);

InputStream is = new FileInputStream(input);

String html = IOUtils.toString(is);

Document htmlDoc = Jsoup.parse(html);

Elements pElements = htmlDoc.select("P");

Element pElement1 = pElements.get(0);
```